# Handling large URL query parameters for SPA

Tags: url, server, hosting, single-page-application, query-string

So, I've recently finished my SPA and published it online. The application allows you to create content and share your content by providing a permalink. The permalink is generated by stringifying the object, encrypting it, making it URL safe, and tacking it onto the base url as a query parameter.

The problem I'm facing, is that when the user creates content that causes the JS object to be large, the URL of course becomes large as well. I want the application to be able to handle any size, but my site crashes with a `Request-URI Too Long` error.

The alternative I've considered is setting up a back-end that can take the data and provide an id of some kind to use in the url instead, so my application can just call the back-end with the id to fetch the data.

I'd like to avoid doing that if possible though, as I don't really feel like paying for the server onto of already paying for my site hosting. I'm hosting the site on my GoDaddy account, but have seen other sites handle obscenely large URLs through NameCheap, not sure if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

Hash the content with a hash such as SHA-256, Base64 encode the hash, URL encode it and use that as the permalink or at least part of it.

Comment: At the moment I'm doing all of that except hashing the content with SHA-256. Would adding that step still help do you think?

Comment: The point of the hash is that it is the same size for all input lengths.

Comment: If I did it this way, I don't see how it would be possible to decrypt the hash to get the content back.

Comment: You don't need to decrypt the hash, just use it to lookup the content, possibly using it as the access/file name.